# Should unit test project has reference to EF dll when context is abstracted

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, dbcontext

I am abstracting my DbContext in an attempt to address Separate of Concerns and make my code unit-testable. In order to do that I have come up with following interface.

This interface below is hosted in Assembly named **AllInterfaces**. This project has a reference to EF dll due to IDbSet in declaration below.

```
public interface ISalesContext : IDisposable   
{   
  IDbSet<Customer> Customers { get; }   
  IDbSet<Order> Orders { get; }   
  IDbSet<Product> Products { get; }    
}
```

I also created a fake db set as follows.

```
public class FakeDataSet<T> : IDbSet<T> where T: class, new()
{
 .......
}
```

So for my Customer object, this fake dataset look like below.

```
public class FakeCustomerDbSet : FakeDbSet<Customer>
    {
     ..............
    }
```

Then I created my fake context as follows.

```
public class FakeSalesContext : ISalesContext 
    {
        public FakeSalesContext ()
        {
            Customers = new FakeCustomerDbSet ();

        }

        public IDbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public IDbSet<Order> Orders{ get; private set; }
        public IDbSet<Product> Products { get; private set; }

        public void Dispose()
        {

        }
    }
```

All the above classes (FakeDataSet,  FakeCustomerDbSet and FakeSalesContext ) related to fake objects live in an assembly **AllFakes**. I had to add a reference to EF dll as IDbSet interface is referred in these fake classes as well.

Then I have my unit test project where I am using fake objects for performing unit testing.

```
ISalesContext Context = new FakeSalesContext ();
Context.Customers.Add(new Customer() { Id = 1, LastName = "Karen" } );
```

Problem is that this unit test requires me to add reference to Entity framework dll. If I remove EF reference, I get following compilation error.

> The type 'System.Data.Entity.IDbSet`1' is defined in an assembly
>   that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

If I remove EF dll reference from AllFakes assembly, I get following  error.

> The type or namespace name 'IDbSet' could not be found (are you 
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Does it make sense to add a reference to EF dll to all these assemblies? To me, since I have abstracted my db context, it should not be needed here. Any suggestions on how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need a reference to EF dll. You did abstract your context but your abstraction is still using IDbSet interface which is defined in the EntityFramework.dll. FakeSalesContext exposes public properties of IDbSet type if you don't add a reference to EntityFramework.dll (where IDbSet is defined) things will not compile since the compiler will not know what the IDbSet is.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I do not see an issue with it. As long as you are only testing your `DbContext` implementations, the reference itself is only for dependency resolution by your context object.